# How to identify SMD component

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, surface-mount, short-circuit

I am trying to investigate an issue with an FPV quad that I have, on my flight controller, there is continuity between the ground and 5v pads, people tell me this means that one of the 5v regulators on the pcb has gone bust.

I have taken pictures of the component I suspect, but I can't understand what the component code means - **DE=U3P**.  ??????

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please help to identify what this is?

[image: Top side of flight controller]
[image: bottom side of flight controller]

Comment: What's the point of identifying it? If it's broken, then probably because more on the regulator board was fried, so you'll need to replace that supply.

Comment: Measure continuity on this part and if shorted, remove and repeat test. It may be a dual LDO (3.3,1.7) supplied by 5V but not the short you are looking for.

Comment: I have two of these on the board and want to find out if this one is a 5v regulator or not? I have bought some BEC 5v voltage regulators and already wired those into the stuff that needed 5v supply, now I need to bring 5v back onto my flight controller pcb board, but before I do so, I need to eliminate whatever is shorting the ground and 5v pads on the board, which seems that a busted regulator might be doing.

Comment: Measure the short in mOhms and start tracing the short with a small pulse. 0.1V 0 ohms or use a Lab supply with CC and CV to trace lowest voltage starting with 0.1V @ ? mA. If really low R, more current will dissipate heat. Then remove and measure voltage on good part.

Comment: If only i had all that gear, all I have a multimeter. All I know is that 5v supply on the board has gone and the ground and 5v rails short somewhere, that probably means busted 5v regulator. Just need to find which one, hence why I was asking about the component numbering system

Comment: There's no system. Every manufacturer just slaps whatever nonesense on they see fit.

Comment: Seems im stuck then, will have to order a completely new PCB.

Comment: If it is a dual LDO (3.3,1.7), can you roughly point out where on the board it is???

Comment: Founded this starting with     DE=      RT9193-33GB Richtek Technology
SOT-23-5 Linear voltage regulator IC  LDO, 3.3V±1%, 300mA, +CE . Hope wil help.

Comment: I forget the link    https://smd.yooneed.one/code4445.html